# Проверка тернарным условием в php

Tags: php

Как в php проверить одно условие тернарным способом ?

```
if ($a){
  return "OK";
}
```

Comment: Зачем? Не проще просто написать `if ($a) return "OK";`

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае тернарный оператор применить не получится, так как сам по себе тернарный оператор предполагает выбор между несколькими вариантами.
Иными словами, если бы у вас было:

```php
if ($a){
    return "OK";
} else {
    return "NOT OK"
}
```

Можно было бы использовать:

```php
   return $a ? "OK" : "NOT OK"
```

Выражение `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` интерпретируется как expr2, если expr1 имеет значение TRUE, или как expr3, если expr1 имеет значение FALSE.

Начиная с версии PHP 5.3 также стало возможным не писать среднюю часть тернарного оператора. Выражение `expr1 ?: expr3` возвращает expr1 если expr1 имеет значение TRUE и expr3 в противном случае.

[Операторы сравнения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Также, начиная с PHP 7, добавился новый оператор "??" (null coalescing).

```php
// Пример использования оператора
$action = $_POST['action'] ?? 'default';

// Пример выше аналогичен следующему коду
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
   $action = $_POST['action'];
} else {
   $action = 'default';
}
```

Comment: и как это соотносится к `return "Ok"` из вопроса?

Comment: Добавил пояснения к вопросу.

Comment: @teran чего пристал к человеку? товарищ сюда пришел отвечать на вопросы, а не читать их

Answer (score 3):

Тернарный оператор должен возвращать значение для обеих веток - как для случая, когда проверка возвращает true, так и для false

Поскольку в приведенном примере есть только одна ветка, то заменить его на тернарный оператор нельзя

Answer (score -2):

Вот такое решение нашел `$a ?: return "OK";`

Comment: и про `unexpected return` там ничего нет?

Comment: Кто апвотит такую ересь?